# How to organize a connection, with 2 classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Category
  has_many :services
end


class Service
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :order
end

class Order
  has_many :services
end
```

How to organize a connection, where I can refer to orders from an object of the category,
It is natural that orders are specifically in this category for services that are
they have.

For example:

```
category = Category.first
category.orders
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

```
class Category
  has_many :services
  has_many :orders, through: :services
end
```

I recommend you take a look at the [Rails association basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Thank's! it helped for me.